# PHP and MySQL related Problem

Tags: mysql, php

I have a local LAN to my office. Recently I designed a New Software system using PHP, MySQL for my office. My boss wants to see the reports from online.

My problem is, my network connection is often failed to my office. But I have to input all time.

So, now I want to use two instances of my software. One will be using the LAN and one will be uploaded to my server.

My question is, how can I easily keep the both databases up-to-date always?

Please help me with this issue. If you want more info please feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html).

Comment: How can I Set the Replication Slave Configuration using CPanel?

Comment: Dunno. Call CPanel support.